# Navbar blocks content when I click on an anchor to target an element

Tags: html, css

The navbar blocks the content when I navigate to an element by using the anchor to target an element.
I've tried adding `margin-top: 80px` but it doesn't work. The content is still blocked.

```css
body {
  height: 400vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 30px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

header * {
  display: inline;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background: #8ee4af;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav a {
  top: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 28px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #05386b;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
<main>
  <p id="About">LOL</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Please provide codes instead of images.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please clarify your question and title, thank you

Comment: Add Padding Top to the section you wanna scroll to.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: I've added the code, sorry for the inconvenience guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `anchor` to target an `id` will always move the `:target` element to the top of the viewport (or as close to the top as technical possible). As such your navbar will "cut" the content. The easiest solution is to use: `*:target { padding-top: value; }` to add a padding-top to the targeted element that is higher then the navbar itself.

```css
*:target {
  padding-top: 40px;
}




/* for styling pupose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  padding: 10px;
}

section:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: darkblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#section-1">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#section-2">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#section-3">Section 3</a>
  <a href="#section-4">Section 4</a>
</nav>

<section id="section-1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
<section id="section-2">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
<section id="section-3">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
<section id="section-4">
  <h1>Section 4</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
```