# offsetting anchor link with a sticky header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a navbar and a sticky header which you can check it out in snippet. Now if i click on my anchors, I get scrolled down to the right position, even the header doesn't overlap the text of the div except in one strange case.
the problem is when i'm in the #Home section, after clicking on any anchors ( no matter #AboutMe or #Skills), it sends me to the right position but the header overlaps the text a little bit which is not what i want.
so when i'm in #AboutMe section and click on #Skills anchor for example, nothing strange happens and everything is alright but the problem is when you are in the #Home section and you wanna get to another sections by clicking on their anchors, it sends you a little bit lower than where it should get you.

to find out what i mean exactly, you need to click on `#AboutMe` anchor twice when you are in `#Home` section ( same as `#Skills` anchor) then you will find out on first attempt, it's not doing the job properly and you need to click on that specific anchor, twice to get the result you're looking for.

NOTE: ignore other styles like texts positioning or images which are not really important here and the snippet i've provided is enough to show you what my issue is.
has anybody ever faced this strange issue?

JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/f715j3qh/120/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var aboveHeight = $('header').height();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight) {
            $('nav').addClass('fixed').css('top', '0').next().css('padding-top', '70px');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.header {
    text-align: center;
}

.header-top {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    height: 210px;
    background: #28223f;
}

.header-top-p {
    padding: 40px 0 30px;
}

.header p{
    color:#a8c6de;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}


#header-nav {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10000;
}

nav .mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

#header-nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header-nav ul li.active {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: -3px 3px 7px #4d4d00;
}

nav .mainMenu li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    padding: 21px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.anchor {
    display: block;
    height: 70px; 
    margin-top: -70px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#Matin-Pic {
    background: #28223f;
    min-height: 63vh;
}

.Matin-Picture {
    margin: 15px auto;
    color: #b3b8cd;
    width: 380px;
    background: brown;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.cover-photo {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 130px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.non-profile {
    height: 130px;
    width: 100%;
}

.non-profile img {
    height: 160px;
    width: 175px;
    margin: auto 150px;
    display: flex;
}

.profile {
    height: 140px;
    width: 105px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #1f1a32;
    padding: 7px;
    background: #292343;
    margin: -70px 0 0 203px;
}

.profile-name {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 25px 0 0 -100px;
}

.about {
    margin-top: 35px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

#Matin-Pic button {
    margin: 15px 10px 30px;
}

.msg-btn, .follow-btn {
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightblue;
    color: brown;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    padding: 10px 25px;
}

.follow-btn {
    background: transparent;
    color: lightblue;
}

#Matin-Pic i {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: lightblue !important;
}

.section-1 {
    background: #fff;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.section-1 img {
    margin-top: 160px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#AboutMe-image img:nth-child(1) {
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px blue;
    display: block;
}

#AboutMe-image img:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px blue;
}

.section-1-image img {
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px blue;
}

.section-1 h3 {
    font-style: oblique;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 60px auto;
    color: blue;
}

.section-1 p {
    color: black;
}

.section-1 p:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.section-1 p:nth-child(3) {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 2.5;
}

#AboutMe {
    margin-bottom: 110px;
    min-height: 78vh;
}

#AboutMe-Text {
    padding-right: 50px;
}

#Skills {
    background: rgba(168, 198, 222, 0.2);
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 300px 15px;
}

.section-2 ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.section-2 ul li {
    margin: 52px auto 0;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: black;
}

.section-2 ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.section-2 ul li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 52px;
}

.section-2 img {
    margin: 32px auto;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: 540px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.main-titles {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="Home">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <header class="header header-top">
                <div class="header-top-p col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="header-top-p col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </header>
            <nav id="header-nav">
                <ul class="mainMenu">
                    <li class="Home"><a href="#Home" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="AboutMe"><a href="#AboutMe-anchor" class="nav-item">About Me</a></li>
                    <li class="Skills"><a href="#Skills-anchor" class="nav-item">Skills</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--end Home section and header-->

<!-- ***** card profile ***** -->
<div id="M-Pic" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="M-Picture">
        <div class="cover-photo">
            <div class="non-profile">
                <img src="Content/images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <img src="Content/images/MPic.jpg"
                                                                                  class="profile">
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">text</div>
        <p class="about">some text here<br>some text</p>
        <button class="msg-btn" onclick="#">send</button>
        <button onclick="#" class="follow-btn">button1
        </button>
        <div>
            <a href="#"><i
                    class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i
                    class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<span class="anchor" id="AboutMe-anchor"></span>
<section id="AboutMe" style="padding-top:3rem;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-1">
                <div id="AboutMe-image" class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 slide-in fade-in">
                    <img src="Content/images/bg2-com2.jpg" alt="an image" width="1280" height="850">
                    <img alt="an image" src="Content/images/bg2-com5.jpeg" width="1000" height="800">
                </div>
                <div id="AboutMe-Text" class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 slide-in fade-in">
                    <h3>some text here</h3>
                    <p>some text here</p>
                    <p>some text here<br> some text here
                        <br>
                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr
                      <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr.<br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 section-1-image">
                   <!--  <img alt="an image" src="Content/images/bg2-com.jpg" width="598" height="399" class="fade-in slide-in"> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--end AboutMe-->

<!-- ***** skills ***** -->
<span class="anchor" id="Skills-anchor"></span>
<section id="Skills" style="padding-top:1rem;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-2">
                <h2 class="main-titles fade-in-main-titles slide-in-main-titles">skills</h2>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section-2-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li>item1</li>
                        <li>item2</li>
                        <li>item3</li>
                        <li>item4</li>
                        <li>item5</li>
                        <li>item6</li>
                        <li>item7</li>
                        <li>item8</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <img src="Content/images/MySkills2.gif"
                         class="img-responsive center-block fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section-2-right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>item9</li>
                        <li>item10</li>
                        <li>item11</li>
                        <li>item12</li>
                        <li>item13</li>
                        <li>item14</li>
                        <li>item15</li>
                        <li>item16</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: could this approach help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782652/navbar-blocks-content-when-i-click-on-an-anchor-to-target-an-element/68782918#68782918 ?

Comment: hi @tacoshy. no unfortunately. it's not working yet. if you pay attention the difference between my navigation and the link you've sent is that his navigation is fixed at top but my navigation is not at the top of page at the beginning. i changed the styles based on what you said (*:target { padding-top: 70px;} but it didn't work. as i explained, everything's alright when you wanna go from other sections to another but when you wanna go from #Home section to other sections, on first attempt, it's not gonna send you where it should exactly send and you need to click twice on that anchor.